# Running a function in a Mongo insert with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Using the instructions [from the Mongo site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), I created a function to add an auto-incrementing value. When I insert something through the Mongo command line, it works.

I'm trying to figure out how to execute the function in a PHP insert. I tried adding it as a string, hoping it would parse, but of course, it stored a string. I can't figure out how to execute it as a function.

EDIT: 
I tried using MongoCode, but now I'm getting an error saying getNextSequence doesn't exist. I tried following the instructions on [db side js](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/), but it still says the function doesn't exist. I'm pretty lost at this point.

Comment: you should create a PHP function that does this, and then call that to get the next id value.  The reason the docs use javascript is because all the examples are in the shell.  you want this function to be the same code/place as your application code.

Comment: Ok, great, I'll do that instead then.